# How may I minimize this function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I want to minimize the given function:

$$f(x, y)=(1-\alpha)x+\alpha\left(y+\frac{1}{c+y}\right)$$
 and $c+y>0, y\ge 0, x\ge 0$ and $0<\alpha<1.$

(1) I minimized it according to $x$ first and the minimum occurs at $x=0$ (let $y+1/(c+y)=b$ we notice that $(1-\alpha)x+b$ increasing and because it is positive the minimum is at $x=0.$)

(2) After that I minimized $f(0, y)$ according to $y$

Is this approach right?

Comment: Are you varying $\alpha$ or $c$ or both?  What is $x=>0 and 0$?  Or are you finding the minimum over $x,y$ with $\alpha, c$ given?  Take the partial derivatives, set them to zero, and check the boundary.

Comment: Please check your question again. Was that what you intended asking?

Comment: \alpha is varying between 0 and 1 but not equal to 0 or 1. c also vary. but i want to minimize over x and y.I ook the partial derivative according to x but that equals to 1-\alpha which does not equal 0. so i minimized first according to x then y. x=>0 means x greater or equal 0.